# local private chain account, switch to test net, start to lose ether?

Tags: private-blockchain, testnets, private-key

I built a local private chain, and created an account via geth.
Then I switched to test net from metamask.

After that, the account started to lose ether. People sent the ether in that account to other accounts.

It doesn't really matter since it's a test net. But I don't understand how it was done.

No one should have access to my private key, right? How do they transfer my test net ether to other accounts?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same "issue" the problem is that if you have your account unlocked and you have open ports to the instance including RPC people can sniff the network, find your node and execute transactions.

If you **unlock** an account then the private key is automatically open for business meaning for any transfers.

So they don't have your private key but as long as it is unlocked (either using RPC or geth) they can make transfers.

Make sure to lock the ports and not unluck the account from the RPC.